# How to Unmount WIndows Partition Disk Permantely

Tags: unmount

I have dual OS (Windows 8 and Ubuntu), when I using Ubuntu, Windows partition Disks are automatically mounted in Explorer. I need to unmount permanently on every boot or permanently. I tried this in Gparted but when reboot it again mounted.
Kindly Share your views.

Comment: Can we get the output of the commands `mount` and `cat /etc/fstab`?

Comment: Somehow I feel this is a duplicate, but I can't find the other question. Something with 'device, nautilus, hide'?

Comment: Just a mention: disks are not mounted automatically. You can see them in nautilus or launcher (not Explorer), but they are (automaticaly) mounted only when you try to open them first time. This being said, [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/334156/147044) is probably the answer that you need.

Comment: @Bobby, Do you need my output for mount and cat /etc/fstab?

Comment: @private, Sorry this not a duplicate question but some how having similarity.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu, Yes you right, I am little new to Ubuntu, so i am not forgetting the windows technical terms while typing. Sorry I will change to call it as nautilus. Now I am asking the query, When the drive is clicked means, its opening but i don`t want to display the available drives in nautilus.

Comment: Just out of curriosity, do you have an entry for that partition in `/etc/fstab` file ?  Typically whatever partition is set to be automounted is in that file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do it nicely (i.e. really not mount the disks rather than mount them somewhere strange) it is a bit more complicated than what is suggested in the other answer. The best guide to follow is:

[Hide your disks or partitions from Nautilus](http://www.worldofnubcraft.com/969/hide-your-disks-or-partitions-from-nautilus/)

I followed the guide just the other day and it worked well. Essentially you create a file `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-hide-disks.rules` in which you put the line

```
KERNEL=="sda1", ENV{UDISKS_PRESENTATION_HIDE}="1"
```

where *sda1* is the name of the partition you want to hide. In some systems ([12.10?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15999973/2115409)) it can also be

```
KERNEL=="sda1", ENV{UDISKS_IGNORE}="1"
```

Then you reboot.

Comment: Thanks for your help and i have a doubt, there is no possible way to unmounted the unnecessary partition after boot instead of hiding it in somewhere. Anyway i try and get back to you once if face any issue.

Comment: With the above solution, the partition will not be shown **and not be mounted**. I think it is what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes you are right, I will try once and get back to you if i found any issue. Thanks for your support

Comment: Its working great.

Comment: Works great on Ubuntu 14.04. Thank you

Comment: The provided link no longer works. It would be great to update the answer when you can!

Comment: The answer contains the basic information necessary, does it not?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a possible workaround:
The issue seems to be you don't want it mounted, I am assuming because it mounts in a certain spot that you don't want?

In this case you could go into fstab and have it auto mount on boot in a completely different location.

/~/donttouchdrive/

[Fstab info](http://www.slackbook.org/html/filesystem-structure-mounting.html)

Comment: Thanks for your help and i have a doubt, i try and get back to you once if face any issue.