# ata5: COMRESET failed (errno=-32) old iMac broken disk

Tags: boot, 20.04, usb, mac, sata

I have a 5,1 iMac with a broken internal disk. After many attempts I got a working installation of Ubuntu 20.04.03 on an external USB drive.

The boot is very long due to a repeated message:

```
COMRESET failed (errno = -32).
```

`dmesg | grep ata` reports:

```
ata5: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m1024@0x88305000 port 0x88305200 irq 27
...
ata5: COMRESET failed (errno = -32) 
ata5: reset failed (errno=-32), retrying in 33 secs
...
```

I need to skip any check over broken disk.

Comment: You may want to ask on this site https://apple.stackexchange.com/?newreg=7c5214c14ebd48f78fd9fc6e9e267c28 How you can disable that broken disk.

Comment: [This answer from a few years back](https://askubuntu.com/a/554417/1222991) may give you what you’re looking for 